# Android: Solution for Social Features in app

Tags: android, social-networking

I have an android app, the app has some contents and i want to add social features for the contents (like, comment, editing). So what is the best solution for me? Is there any online service or ... for this?

Note: I don't want to use other social networks (Facebook, Twitter, ...)

Thanks

Comment: You can make web services for this

Comment: I want a comprehensive solution that handle server side of the problem

Comment: You can make web services for all CRUD operation

Comment: Ok,I understand what  you mean, thanks. but i want a solution or service that handle all CRUD operations for me